# Want to execute a shell script present on remote linux server while passing 2 arguments from local AIX server

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting, aix

I am trying to execute a local `test.sh` script and connect to a remote Linux box using `ssh`, passing 2 arguments. Once connected to a remote server I want to execute `test1.sh` which internally calls my Python script using the 2 arguments passed. I am not able to connect and execute the `test1.sh` script.

Can someone help with what's wrong with what's being passed? Below is the used commands:

**Local test.sh file:**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
ssh testusername@remoteserever
cd /home/tibco
./test1.sh "$1" "$2"
```

**Test1.sh script:**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
cd /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fuzzywuzzy
python testargs.py "$1" "$2"
```

Comment: Is it correct that the `test.sh` script is supposed to execute the `test1.sh` script on the remote system and that the `test1.sh` script is located on the remote system?

Comment: You'll probably want `ssh testusername@remoteserever /home/tibco/test1.sh "$1" "$2"`

Comment: Could try with quotes: `ssh testusername@remoteserever
"cd /home/tibco; ./test1.sh \"$1\" \"$2\""` or rather: `ssh testusername@remoteserever
"cd /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fuzzywuzzy;
python testargs.py \"$1\" \"$2\""`

Answer (score 1):

What you have starts an interactive `ssh`, waits for it to end, the changes directory and tries to run a script.

Try
`ssh testusername@remoteserever /home/tibco/test1.sh "$@"`